# Не работает PHP "$_GET" внутри jQuery ".click"

Tags: php, jquery

У меня на сайте выезжающая панель с формой регистрации. То есть, при нажатии на кнопку "зарегистрироваться" страница не обновляется, просто панель уезжает и всплывает `alert`:

> "на e-mail выслано письмо...".

Вот такой у меня код:

```
 $sticker.click(function() {
                if ($panel.hasClass('visible')) {

                    <?php if($_GET["email"]==""||$_GET["pass"]==""){ ?>
                    alert("Введите e-mail и пароль!"); 
                    <?php } else {?>

                    hidePanel();

                    <?php } ?>
                }
                else {

                    showPanel();
                }
            });
```

И вот, что бы я ни писал в `"email"` и `"pass"`, у меня всегда всплывает:

> "Введите e-mail и пароль!".

Comment: _что бы я ни писал в "email" и "pass"_ - где именно ты пишешь в "email" и "pass"?

Comment: @Grundy , в `<input type="text"  name="email">` и `<input type="password" name="pass">` соответственно. Которые находятся внутри `form` с `action="get"`. И `form` уже находится в `div` с самой панелью.

Answer (score 1):

потому что на момент загрузки страницы у вас параметры $_GET["email"] и $_GET["pass"] не существуют и в вашей проверке: этот кусок кода

```
<?php if($_GET["email"]==""||$_GET["pass"]==""){ ?>
```

как бы говорит и отрабатывает.. если вы хотите проверять введенные данные, то вам нужно jsом ловить данные введенные в поля формы, делается это примерно так на jquery:

```
email=$('id или класс поля email формы ').val();
pass=$('id или класс поля pass формы').val();
```

а дальше проверка

```
 if(email==''||pass==''){
     alert("Введите e-mail и пароль!"); 
 }else{
     hidePanel();// ваша функция закрытия видимо
 }
```

Comment: Но я специально использовал php, чтобы потом вносить данные в mysql базу данных, как же мне это сделать на jquery?

Comment: @iamsolame, а ты знаешь чем отличается php от javascript(jquery)?

Comment: @Grundy , php работает с сервером, а JavaScript - с браузером?

Comment: я думаю обучать вас основам web  программирования в комментариях не является задачей ресурса

Comment: @BroouzerKing , да мне и не надо, я просто хочу решить свою проблему. И, я так понимаю, то, что я пытаюсь сделать, - это бред? Единственное, что мне поможет, - это аякс?

Comment: @BroouzerKing вам "пытаются" донести что ваша проверка `<?php if($_GET["email"]==""||$_GET["pass"]==""){ ?>` выполниться еще до того как что либо будет введено в вашу форму, так как php будет обработан на момент вывода страницы, и больше не участвует в проверке. Если посмотрите исходный код страницы в браузере, то у вас будет только одна запись - `alert("Введите e-mail и пароль!"); `. Собственно по этому вам нужно проверять введенные данные с помощью js а не с помощью php.